Equalizer effect for AVPlayer
Please tell me how can I add an equalizer effect to AVPlayer?
The code is below:
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var player: AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://music.mp3") else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        player?.play()
    }
}


